# bash script - loop through files and add to different variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have files with names like:

```
0195_R1.fastq
0195_R2.fastq
0196_R1.fastq
0196_R2.fastq
0197_R1.fastq
0197_R2.fastq
```

and so on.

I need to run a software for each pair of files (the R1 and R2 are correspondent to each other) like:

```
bowtie2 -x index_files -1 0195_R1.fastq -2 0195_R2.fastq -S 0195_output.sam
```

With multiple pairs I'd have to run multiple times.
So I tried to do a bash script using a for loop but I've had no success.
Also, I don't know how to rename the output sequentially.

I've tried the following:

```
for R1 in $FQDIR/*_R1.fastq; do
for R2 in $FQDIR/*_R2.fastq; do

    bowtie2 -x index_files -1 $R1 -2 $R2 -S $N_output.sam

done
done
```

What should I do?

Comment: `for R1 in $FQDIR/*_R1.fastq; do
for R2 in $FQDIR/*_R2.fastq; do` this will do `for each R1 and for each R2`, so every combination. Do it simpler - just iterate over `R1` files, so the first loop, then extract the `<this part>_R1.fastq` of the filename with `basename` and `cut`. Then when you have "this part" then it's easy. Note that `$N_output` would be intepreted as the variable `N_output` you probably want `${N}_output`.

Comment: Those indexes will do the job `for i in {195..197}; { bowtie2 -x index_files -1 0195_R1.fastq -2 *${i}_R2.fastq -S *${i}_output.sam; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you loop over all the R1 and R2 files, you'll run `bowtie` for all possible pairs of data files. If I understand correctly, that's not what you want - you only want to process the corresponding pairs.

To do that, loop over R1 files only, and try to find the corresponding R2 file for each:

```
#!/bin/bash
fqdir=...
for r1 in "$fqdir"/*_R1.fastq; do
    r2=${r1%_R1.fastq}_R2.fastq
    if [[ -f $r2 ]] ; then
        bowtie2 -x index_files -1 "$r1" -2 "$r2" -S "$N"_output.sam
    else
        echo "$r2 not found" >&2
    fi
done
```

I'm not sure what `$N` stands for. Maybe you can use `$r1` instead?

Comment: Seems like `$N` is just the number prefixing each pair, so you can replace it with `${r1/_*/}`.

Comment: Another point that I think can be improved (just for clarity)  is `r2=${r1/_R1/_R2}` instead of `r2=${r1%_R1.fastq}_R2.fastq`.

Comment: The $N is for the number prefixing each pair. I replaced it with $r1. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Replacing `$N` with just `$r1` will give you something like `0195_R1.fastq.output`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @accdias now I've seen your comment and used your solution too. Thanks!

Comment: @accdias: Using substitution is more dangerous: the path might contain `_R1` somewhere else, too.

Comment: @choroba, you are right. I forgot the code is using the full path in the `for` loop.